# Hashing algorithm which minimizes distribution

Tags: algorithms, hash, probabilistic-algorithms, hashing

Consider applications `A1, A2 .. AN` having properties `P11, P12,... PN1, PN2..` Also consider buckets `B1, B2 ... BN` where each **property** needs to be mapped. We have the following constraints -

```
total number of properties >> number of applications

total number of properties >> number of buckets

number of buckets ~= number of applications
```

Is there a hash algorithm which minimizes the number of distinct application each bucket is mapped to while still guaranteeing even distribution of properties? In other words, if one of the buckets were to be *hidden* temporarily, the number of distinct applications affected should be minimal.

Comment: If it exists, as they are a finite number you can check all. Not exactly efficient, though.

Comment: @vonbrand did you mean to suggest going through all existing hash functions?

Comment: Do you really need the absolute minimum, or is something that is close to minimal acceptable?  A random assignment is likely to be pretty good (close to optimal) when all three numbers are large.

Comment: Close to minimum @D.W.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to incorporate that information.  We want questions to stand on their own, so people don't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/46761/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/125080/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).